# Why $().draggable({revert: true}) doesn't response during if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using jQuery, I want to drag text div anywhere. Then if the user decide want to move the div text back to original position, they will have to select option that say "return" then the div text will move to original. However, that doesn't work at all, result are either still there or text disappear. Without if statement, either of draggable method worked. I think it had to do with if statement but I am not sure, please help.

Here my jQuery/javascript code,

```
var selected = '2 line';
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#options").change(function(){ // function that do option selection
            selected = $("option:selected", this).val();

        });

        if(selected == 'return position')
        {
               $( "#subtitle" ).draggable({revert: true})
        }else
        {
            $( "#subtitle" ).draggable({revert: false})
        }
    });
```

Comment: There is something wrong in your logic, see @Daniel A. White's answer

Comment: So the code inside of `$(document).ready()` only runs once. Your change function is set up, and then you immediately check `selected` (which won't equal return position). You'll then never check it again. If you want it to check every time `$('#options')` changes, you'll need to put it inside the change function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That option is being set out side of the `change` event. don't you mean to set it inside that callback?

Comment: The selected variable is declared in global. So it shouldn't matter if inside or outside. I had other function that is not in there example work well with option outside of change event.

Comment: @StudentIT where is it initially set?